# How to automatically increase/decrease order if create a new order request in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, database

I want to make one of my data 'order' automatically increase or decrease depends on new request order.

The data like this

| id | order |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |

The request is to insert a new id and its order is 2, then the origin id 2 and 3's order need to decrease 1 like this:

| id | order |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 2 |

or the request is update id 3's order to 1 then other's order need to change automatically like:

| id | order |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 3 |

I have no idea how to achieve this result in node.js.
Please help or some suggestion will be very appreciate.